# js get part of the url

Tags: javascript

I tried use js to change my url from

`http://localhost/text/index.php#mainpage%20menu1`

to

`http://localhost/text/index.php#homepage%20menu1`

My code not work, need a help, thanks.

```
var curl = document.location.href;
var index = window.location.hash;
curl = index !== -1 ? index.split("%20",1) : null;
index = "homepage%20" + curl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a string replace:

```
var curl = document.location.href;
curl = curl.replace("mainpage", "homepage");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `replace`, e.g.

```
var curl = document.location.href;
curl = curl.replace("mainpage", "homepage");
```